# Loading multiple series into highcharts via JSON. How to parse?

Tags: json, parsing, highcharts

I have a JSON source that look like this... ( I checked it at jsonlint and it appears valid )

`[{
    "day": "06/19/2016",
    "region": "Ohio",
    "daily_er": "98.61"
}, {
    "day": "06/19/2016",
    "region": "Western NE",
    "daily_ef": "98.63"
}, {.........`

I'm trying to load the day as the y Axis with the region as X Axis

In my experimentation with loading from a local CSV, I DID manage to get the below to work....

(data.csv)

`Categories,06/19/16,06/20/16,06/21/16,06/22/16,06/23/16,06/24/16,06/25/16
Ohio,98.61,97.75,97.19,97.21,97.97,93.66,98.3
Western NE,98.63,98.42,98.25,98.27,98.29,98.35,98.24`

`$.get('data.csv', function(data) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');`

```
// Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
    var items = line.split(',');        
    // header line containes categories
    if (lineNo == 0) {
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
            if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
        });
    }
    else {
        var series = {
            data: []
        };
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
            if (itemNo == 0) {
                series.name = item;
            } else {
                series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
            }
        });
        options.series.push(series);
    }  
});

// Create the chart
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

});

I want to apologize up front because while in my mind I get how CSV gets parsed, I so rarely work with JSON that I am stumped as to how I parse the JSON above. In my brain I'm getting hung up on dupes for the day values and how that's handled. Has anyone had an experience with this they'd like to share, maybe get me pointed in the right direction?
Many thanks!
JW

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how you would like to load your day as yAxis and region as xAxis. Do you have any example of your charts? Here you can see an example how I have changed your data to show the chart that may meet your requirements: https://jsfiddle.net/paLoxcy3/6/

Comment: Grzegorz, this is perfect! I'm a backend developer so web development isn't a strong suit. Any idea how I'd use the getJSON on this? You are the best! JW

Comment: Happy to read my comment helped you. About getJSON - It should be almost the same. The data I have used is the data that should  be the output from your getJSON.